# How do I print a formatted number to the screen in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, printf

I am trying to format a matrix in C# as shown:

```
 1  2
10 11
```

I could do this in C using:

```
printf("%2d",number)
```

Is there a similar command in C#? I have tried `String.Format` and `ToString`, but I can't figure out how to make them do what I want. I am just starting out in C#, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `number.ToString("D2")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to a `%2d` for printf, in C#:

```
string s=string.Format("{0,2}",number);
```

The number after the comma right aligns if positive and left aligns if negative, to the specified number of total characters (including the `number` itself).

Here is a link to a [helpful site](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-int/) with a guide on how to format integers in various ways that may help you with the rest of your problem.